# Change/Rename subpages in my URL

Tags: php, html, url, url-rewriting, file-rename

I currently have: www.MYPAGE.com/category (a site I reach from my shop site)

But I want: www.MYPAGE.com/shop/category (so the subpages kinda stack)

So how do I actually achieve that ? Working with *.htaccess* or a more simple way ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want .htaccess

> ```
> # Redirect old file path to new file path
> Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
> ```

but you can use framework route if you use one

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not using a CMS (Wordpress ect) and are just using plain old html.

To change the URL structure simply change  **directory** structure.

So for example put your **category** `index.html` file in the directory `/shop/category/` and the hyperlink to that page is now `www.MYPAGE.com/shop/category/`

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, so I'll risk a bad answer.

Up front, it's been a while since I used php (php4). But we never used php without some other software, usually Apache, to actually serve pages.

A quick check on the php and pear documentation sites doesn't show me that the situation has changed much.

Therefore, I'll start with the simplest description I can remember.

Your server machine runs an OS. You have a web server such as Apache, Nginx, Microsoft's IIS, lighttpd, etc., fielding queries from the web in http protocol. (Skipping discussion of https, look that up later.)

If we were using [Apache's httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/), there would be a configuration file for Apache, usually called httpd.conf. In a Linux or Unix environment, this is usually under /etc/(somewhere) in the file system. In that file, you would have a declaration of the [document root directory](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot).

Unless you add other configurations, the directories under the declared document root are available to the web as they are in your file system. So, if the document root is set as /var/www and your your domain name (which is a separate topic I assume you are not asking about) is set up as in your example -- www.MYPAGE.com, then the file

```
/var/www/aboutus.html
```

would be available on the web as

```
www.MYPAGE.com/aboutus.html
```

and the directory

```
/var/www/shop/
```

would be available on the web as

```
www.MYPAGE.com/shop/
```

Apache allows you to redefine that structure with configuration directives such as Alias and ScriptAlias. Script configurations are the basics for hooking php into your httpd server. Apache's configurations for those can be found from their documentation page on url mapping, which you can find through the links above. (I don't have enough cred to post more than two URLS, sorry.)

You might want to look at virtual hosts (vhost) as well, but focus on Aliases for now.

Say you have product photos in

```
/var/app/products/photos
```

You could have an Alias like this:

```
Alias "/shop/images" "/var/app/products/photo"
```

and (if I remember right and if you don't have locations and url re-writing set up) they would be available on the web at

www.MYPAGE.com/shop/images

And, since I don't have enough cred to post more links, that's as far as I can go with this. Take a quick look at mod_rewrite in the httpd documentation.

Then look in the php documentation for related configuration directives, and it should take you maybe a day of practice at most to understand the basics.

Do get your boss or teacher to allow you to use the time and hardware to practice. Otherwise, your productivity will be stuck in the mud.